# GSON not de-serializing properly nested map with generic key/value

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON to deserialise a JSON string to a JAVA object containing a nested Map with generic key/value.
From my debugging I see GSON converts the first generic type to the correct object. But the second is not converted and therefore acts as a string.

```
class A {
    public B<C_Enum> b = new B<C_Enum>();
}
class B<T> {
    private Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<T, T>();
}
enum C_Enum {
    VAL1, VAL2;
}
main() {
    String json = "{\"b\": {\"map\": {\"NOT_VALID\": \"NOT_VALID\"}}}";
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson customDeserializer = builder.create();
    A a = customDeserializer.fromJson(json, A.class);
}
```

In this example the map is populated with a null key because NOT_VALID is not a valid C_Enum value, and the value of the map is populated with NOT_VALID.
Note: my real code is a bit different but the problem is the same

Comment: Interesting. If you register a zero-serializer type adapter factory whose `create` method would only be the following statements, `System.out.println(typeToken); return null;`, you'd see that Gson does not have enough runtime type information: `java.util.Map<C_Enum, T>` where `T` is a type parameter, not a real type, thus Gson deserializes it as a string, not as an enum. I'm not sure whether it's possible to propagate the type information in the built-in reflective type adapter factory, but is it possible for you not to use type parameters?

Comment: Well.. first the right way is to have it typed. Second, as I noted my real code is a bit different from what I pasted and so after some checking I see it is quite difficult to remove the type and use something else

Comment: I didn't mean "remove the types" therefore not typed, I meant "not to use type parameters".

Comment: Sorry but i still don't understand the difference.
Anyway, I did a workaround by adding an adapter factory which stores the type of class A, and then for class B uses the type to create the right adapter. This was possible because class A is also parametrized with the same type as B (and not as I previously showed)

Comment: ```
TypeToken classAType; //taken from class A
Type classAGenericType = ((ParameterizedType) classAType.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
Type classBGenericTypeParam = TypeToken.getParameterized(B.class, classAGenericType).getType();
TypeToken<?> classBGenericTypeParamToken = TypeToken.get(classBGenericTypeParam);
TypeAdapter<T> defaultAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, classBGenericTypeParamToken);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify this question a little bit, do you mean with "first generic type to the correct object" the `T` as key type for `Map<T, T>`? There is [GitHub issue 1390](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1390) (and an accompanying pull request) which sounds similar to your problem.

Comment: +1. I meet the same issue, use the map like `Map<SOME_ENUM, T>map`, and `gson.toJson()` will not serialize the key use the name after @SerializedName

Comment: @YoniZadik could you share your code via gist or other code editor, I need the same code too

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue

```
Map<SOME_ENUM, T>map;
// gson will not use @SerializedName in the SOME_ENUM
String badJson = new Gson().toJson(map)
```

change it to

```
Map<SOME_ENUM, T>map;
// gson is good
String goodJson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create().toJson(map)
```

link to [gson/issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/473#issuecomment-138103790)